With Gimp3, Merge-Down Keeping Mask?
I'm using Gimp 3.0 and have two layers, the lower with a mask.  I want to merge-down the upper layer keeping the mask but the mask is always removed by the merge.
How can I merge-down keeping the mask of the lower layer?

I took @BillyKerr's answer and simplified it a bit to avoid the creation of a temporary third layer:

Right-click on the lower layer mask and select "Masks to selection".
Right-click on the upper layer and select "Merge down". The selection will remain and not affect the merge.
Right-click on the merged layer (now without any mask) and select "Add layer masks..." then "selection".

Note: This has to be done outside of any group that has its own layer mask or that outer mask will limit the "merge down".

cool, yeah I didn't think of that! +1

In 2.10 and 3.00, if, on the top layer, if you use Composite mode > Clip to backdrop (right-click menu in Layers list) you probably don't even need to merge down to obtain what you want:

To avoid Clip to backdrop to take in account other layers further down, just put the two layers in their own group.
If you merge down the resulting layer has no mask but you can recreate the mask by initializing with transferring the alpha channel, or you do a Mask to selection before the merge and initialize the mask from the selection afterwards.

I tried this.  It does work but I don't want to keep a second layer around and doing "merge-down" of the clipped top-layer still loses the layer mask.  Even if it didn't lose the mask, it would presumably lose the updates in the masked area, which I do want to keep even if I don't want them (currently) seen.

@BrianWhite It's not possible to do it the way you want. because this is the default behaviour in GIMP. There's no way to change it. You need to use a work around.

If it was the "default" then there would be a way to configure it, which was the basis of my question.  But it's apparently un-configurable and therefore a fixed behavior.  But...  Where there's a will there's a way and so we've found ways to work around the limitation.

@BrianWhite You are correct, I should have said "the only behaviour", rather than "default",  because it's not changeable. But you still need to use a work around or make some compromises to achieve it. Either Xenoid's answer or mine will do the trick.  I like Xenoid's answer because of its simplicity so that's a plus one from me.

"I don't want to keep a second layer around" Layers are relatively cheap, and if merging is easy un-merging can be difficult.


Duplicate the masked layer, so you now have three layers

Make sure the duplicate is in the middle, between the two layers

Right click the top layer, and Merge Down

Right click the layer mask, and choose Mask to selection

Select the top layer, Add a layer mask, and choose the option: From Selection

Delete the bottom layer if you no longer need it


Note: GIMP 3.0 has not been released yet. So, you are probably using the release candidate version, which may be buggy.  So I can't guarantee my answer will work for you. I did test it on GIMP 2.10 and it works.

Yes, it's a release-candidate but it's not a bug; it was that way in v2.x as well.  I'm surprised there's still no option to "merge down" that affects that.

@BrianWhite - that's not what I mean.  As far as I know, this behaviour is the same in GIMP 2.10 and the release Candidate.  What I mean is that GIMP 3.0 is at the release candidate stage, and therefore I can't guarantee my answer, will work with it.  I have only tested it in 2.10, and it works.

It works in Gimp3.

@BrianWhite White - cool!
